# Best way to represent a "doubled" enum value

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I'm primarily a C++ developer, but I fairly frequently end up writing Python scripts. I'm currently writing a dice simulator for a game, and I'm not certain of the best way, in Python, the solve my problem.

There are three player skills, and each player is strong at one, medium at one, and weak at one. I've written some classes that calculate the faces of the die from each of the player skils.

The skills live in an enum, rather than writing strings all over the place. However, there's also a chance that the skill will be "doubled", and become stronger.

**Given that I am returning a list of Skill enum element, what is the best way to indicate a skill has been doubled?**

Things I've considered so far:

- Extending the Skill Enum to include doubled skills, but that makes the mapping of player skills to faces harder
- Creating a DoubleSkill Enum, but then any changes to the Skill Enum would need to be replicated in DoubleSkill
- My preferred option, which is creating a wrapper DoubleSkill class that can be constructed from a Skill. However, then it isn't of type enum, which makes my strongly-typed C++ instincts nervous

```
import random
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from enum import Enum
from collections import namedtuple

class Skill(Enum):
    Might = 1,
    Wisdom = 2,
    Cunning = 3

class Die(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def _faces(self):
        '''Returns the faces of this die'''
        pass

    def roll(self):
        '''Returns a random face'''
        return random.choice(self._faces())

PlayerSkills = namedtuple("PlayerSkills", ("strong", "medium", "weak"))

class PlayerDie(Die):
    @abstractmethod
    def _skills(self):
        '''Returns the characer's skills'''
        pass

    def _faces(self):
        '''Work out the faces of the die based off the skills'''
        skills = self._skills()

        #I want this to return a representation of the skill, not a string.
        #But then I'd be mixing Enums and not-Enums
        return [
            self._double(skills.strong),
            self._double(skills.medium),
            skills.strong.name,
            skills.strong.name,
            skills.medium.name,
            skills.weak.name
        ]

    def _double(self, skill):
        return f"Double {skill.name} (block)"

class CookDie(PlayerDie):
    def _skills(self):
        return PlayerSkills(Skill.Might, Skill.Cunning, Skill.Wisdom)

print(CookDie().roll())
```

Comment: You need to remove the comma after each line of the `Enum` definition (otherwise you get a value of `(1, )`, a `tuple`, and not the `int` `1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to make your enumration a `Flag` instead:

```
from enum import Flag, auto
class Skill(Flag):
    Might = auto()
    Wisdom = auto()
    Cunning = auto()
    Doubled = auto()
```

and in use:

```
>>> for i in (1, 2, 4, 9, 10, 12):
...    i, Skill(i)

(1, <Skill.Might: 1>)
(2, <Skill.Wisdom: 2>)
(4, <Skill.Cunning: 4>)
(9, <Skill.Doubled|Might: 9>)
(10, <Skill.Doubled|Wisdom: 10>)
(12, <Skill.Doubled|Cunning: 12>)
```

If you would like a prettier `str()` (or one at all for a combined member), you can add your own `__str__`:

```
class Skill(Flag):
    Might = auto()
    Wisdom = auto()
    Cunning = auto()
    Doubled = auto()
    #
    def __str__(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        cls_name = cls.__name__
        doubled = (self & cls.Doubled or "") and " x2"
        base = (self & ~cls.Doubled) or self
        name = base.name
        if name is None:
            name = '|'.join(s.name for s in Skill if s & base)
        return "%s.%s%s" % (cls_name, name, doubled)
```

and in use:

```
for i in (1, 2, 4, 9, 10, 12):
    i, str(Skill(i))

(1, 'Skill.Might')
(2, 'Skill.Wisdom')
(4, 'Skill.Cunning')
(9, 'Skill.Might x2')
(10, 'Skill.Wisdom x2')
(12, 'Skill.Cunning x2')
```

Comment: This sounds like it could be useful... It also opens the possibility of rolling combinations. So rather than rolling "Double Might" you could roll "Might + Cunning"

Comment: The main downside I'm seeing is that flags or'd together don't have a `name` property, which makes printing them slight less elegant

Comment: I haven't been able to find any information on printing them nicely, so I asked it as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797091/how-to-print-combined-flag-in-the-same-way-as-name-property)

Comment: @Korosia:  Updated my answer and included a bit to have a name for `__str__`.