# How to print combined Flag in the same way as name property

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, enums, flags

In Python, you can use the Flag class to represent combinations of values.

```
class Color(Flag):
    Red = auto()
    Green = auto()
    Blue = auto()
    White = Red | Green | Blue
```

These implicitly convert to strings so you can print them.

```
>>> print(Color.Red, Color.White, Color.Red|Color.Green)
Color.Red Color.White Color.Green|Red
```

The `name` property gives you can even nicer way to print, but it doesn't work for unnamed combined values.

```
>>> print(Color.Red.name, Color.White.name, (Color.Red|Color.Green).name)
Red White None
```

Is there any way to get a combined Flag value to print in a similar way to `name`, without writing a separate function?

e.g.

```
Color.Red | Color.Green  =>  Red Green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  But this sounds like a [good enhancement request](https://bugs.python.org/issue40042).

Comment: Glad to hear its being considered!